# d3.js: extract array in object within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, sub-array

I would like to obtain array in object within array.

Original structure:
**Array [ object, ..., object ]**

```
var dateC = [ 
      {
      key: "2016-01-01",
      values: **[
        {city:"", country:""...},
        {...}
      ]**},
      {
      key: "2016-01-02",
      values: [
        {...},
        {...}
      ]}
]

var dateC2 = dateC.filter(function(d) { return d.key == selected; }).map(function(d) { return d.values })
```

I extracted the object from dateC that has key: "2016-01-01" using the above code.

Current structure:
**Array [ Array[114] ]**

```
var dateC2 = [ 
  {
  key: "2016-01-01",
  values: **[
    {city:"", country:""...},
    {...}
  ]**}
]
```

Desired structure:
**Array [ Object, ..., Object ]**

```
**[{city:"", country:""...}, {...}]**
```

Array that I want is contained by **

I am not sure how I should use **forEach** method to get the array from values because I have already use filter and map on dateC to obtain dateC2. Alternatively, is there a quicker way to obtain the desired structure from original structure?

Comment: please add some more data, especially how the result should look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a single loop for it with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
var dateC2 = dateC.reduce(function(r, d) {
    return d.key == selected ? 
        r.concat(d.values):
        r;
}, []);
```

Comment: I think forEach would be a better choice. (as you mentioned before, no need to return).

Answer (score 1):

I think `Array.prototype.forEach` would be another choice:

```
var dateC2 = [];
dateC.forEach(function(d) {
    if(d.key == selected)
         dateC2 = dateC2.concat(d.values);
});
```

**Or**

```
var dateC2 = [];
dateC.forEach(function(d) {
    if(d.key == selected)
        Array.prototype.push.apply(dateC2, d.values);
});
```

Comment: Hi, why is it better? Is it because it has a better performance?

Comment: @Shawn If this comment is about my comment under [Nina's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38180049/3078890), yes. But you should ask it there not here.